# How to start in lagacy mode instead of uefi

Tags: boot, partitioning, bios

I recently have a problem when i was trying to install windows 10
The installation told me windows cant be installed in mbr drive and you should install it in gpt
So that i tried to convert my drive to gpt using command prompt but it told me you should convert it in lagacy mode instead of uefi
I searched in google for how to start in lagacy mode but the videos explained in old bios menu and my laptop has new bios menu

Please help me how can i start in lagacy in new bios systems

Comment: **[CSM Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#CSM_booting) should _never_ be enabled for an OS**, as its sole purpose was to support distros that didn't yet support EFI boot circa <2017 _(Windows ≥7 supports EFI boot and the only reason to enable CSM Mode is when needing to access a legacy OP[tion] ROM - once done in the OP ROM, CSM Mode should be re-disabled)_. To convert an MBR drive to GPT, ensure CSM Mode is disabled, boot to WinPE/WinRE and use [`Mbr2Gpt`](https://superuser.com/a/1694738/529800)

Answer (score 0):

According to your (unclear) post, I deduce that
you probably have Windows 32-bit installed on an MBR disk and already booted in BIOS
Legacy mode.

You are now trying to install Windows 64-bit which absolutely requires
a disk formatted as GPT (and which can run both in Legacy or non-Legacy BIOS modes).

If you don't care about the data on the disk and are willing to lose everything,
here is how to convert the disk to GPT using the Windows boot media:

1. Turn off the PC, and put in the Windows installation DVD or USB media
2. Boot the PC to the DVD or USB key in
   [UEFI mode](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dn898495%28v=vs.60%29)
   (see the link)
3. From inside Windows Setup, press
   <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>
   to open a command prompt window.
4. Open the diskpart tool:

   ```
   diskpart
   ```
5. Identify the drive to reformat:

   ```
   list disk
   ```
6. Select the drive, and reformat it:

   ```
   select disk <disk number> 
   clean 
   convert gpt 
   exit
   ```
7. Close the command prompt window
8. Continue the Windows Setup installation.
9. When choosing an installation type, select **Custom**.
   The drive will appear as a single area of unallocated space.
10. Select the unallocated space and click **Next**
    for Windows to begin the installation.

Comment: Windows 64-bit absolutely does not require GPT.  If the disk is indeed MBR then the user must enable Compatible Mode to boot to it.  UEFI only mode at least for Windows requires GPT to be used.

Comment: Thanks for your help but i care about my data in my disk

Comment: @Ramhound: I gather he is in UEFI mode.

Comment: @arminpanahi: Then I suggest installing the same Windows version that you have now. But first, since you can boot into command prompt, you can save your data.