# Secure Boot support on a custom-made PC with Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows, secure-boot

As part of my Windows 11 upgrade activities, MS says my PC does not support **Secure Boot**. Something also confirmed by msinfo32.exe:
[msinfo32 snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB0HF.jpg)

Strangely enough, when I entered BIOS it states **Secure Boot state**: “Enabled”:
[BIOS Secure Boot Menu snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V94jU.jpg)

I thus assumed other BIOS settings are also required to be set.

I then tried several combinations values of both this Secure Boot menu (by changing **OS Type**: “Other OS” to “Windows UEFI mode”) and in CSM menu:
[BIOS CSM Menu snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIeR4.jpg)

But my Windows stopped booting whenever I changed **CSM\Launch CSM** to either “Disabled” (no matter the Secure Boot\OS Type value) or “Auto” when **Secure Boot\OS Type** = “Windows UEFI mode”. All other combinations didn’t seem to make any difference for Secure Boot purposes.



I didn’t mess around with **Secure Boot\Key Management** (should I?...):
[BIOS Secure Boot Key Management snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhT1R.jpg)



Digging further, I found a SuperUser posting stating:

> If OS was installed under CSM, it thinks this machine is not UEFI
> compatible and installs in legacy mode. If you switch to UEFI it won't
> boot because this is not UEFI loader expects to see. If system was
> installed under UEFI, it detects that and configures BIOS so it
> wouldn't boot if you switch to CSM afterwards, because this is not
> legacy BIOS loader expects to see. It is possible to configure a
> system to boot either way, but it's not very easy and I don't know how
> to do this in Windows.

As I have a custom-made machine, in which I installed Windows 10 with mostly BIOS defaults, I now suspect that my Windows was installed under CSM.



*So, is there an easy way (say, by tweaking BIOS) to support Secure Boot, without requiring Windows 10 reinstallation?*

**EDIT:**
[image: Actual partition layout]

---

Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit (21H1)
M/B Asus Prime Z370-P
RAM: 16GB
Intel i7 8700
GPU on board (Intel 630)
Broadcom 802.11ac PCIe
Sound Blaster X-Fi Xtreme Audio PCIe

Comment: Windows, or any OS, shouldn't be installed via CSM Mode, as the sole purpose of CSM Mode was to support distros that didn't yet support EFI boot circa <2017 _(≥Win7 supports EFI boot)_. Have a WinPE USB drive available [Windows install USB]: Disable CSM Mode in the UEFI firmware → Boot WinPE → When the GUI loads, press `Shift`+`F10` to access a terminal → Correctly configure Windows for EFI boot _(you'll need to convert the OS partition from MBR to GPT first via a CLI utility - see Microsoft Docs or Superuser; I'll create an answer later, as I don't have time at the moment)_

Comment: @JW0914: Yes, I confirm my partition is MBR. I'll follow your suggestions. Thx!

Comment: @caecilius - Can you indicate how many partitions you currently have on your system disk? You have installed Windows with CSM enabled, which means your NOT using GPT, which also means Secure Boot cannot be enabled until you convert to GPT. Windows 11 does not support MBR. Once I know you have less than 4 partitions I can submit an answer

Comment: @Ramhound - Disk 0 has 3 partitions (See Edit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[CSM Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#CSM_booting) should *never* be enabled for an OS**, as its sole purpose was to support distros that didn't yet support EFI boot circa <2017 *(Windows ≥7 supports EFI boot)*; CSM Mode emulates BIOS' 16bit architecture within a 32bit environment and doing so will cause performance degradation *(boot times increase by 400%+, GPT can't be used, etc.)*

- The only reason to enable CSM Mode is when needing to access a legacy OP[tion] ROM, and once done in the OP ROM, CSM Mode should be re-disabled

**To resolve:**

1. [Windows 10 installation media](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691209) → install on another PC → Save ISO
2. Create bootable USB with [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/) → Reboot → Disable CSM Mode in the UEFI firmware
3. Boot Windows install USB → When GUI loads, open terminal via <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>
4. Use [`mbr2gpt`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/mbr-to-gpt) to convert partition table to GPT:

   1. Ascertain OS disk #: `DiskPart` → `lis disk` → `exit`
   2. ```bash
      mbr2gpt /convert /disk:#
      ```
5. Create required [UEFI-boot](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bringup/boot-and-uefi) partitions on the OS HDD via [`DiskPart`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart):

   1. `DiskPart` → `lis disk` → `sel dis #` → Verify it's the OS disk: `lis par`
   2. Delete old boot partition: `sel par #` → Verify: `det par` → `del par override`
   3. Determine disk layout: `lis par` *(optimal partition layout: WinRE, EFI, MSR, OS)*
   4. Add requisite UEFI partitions:

      1. [WinRE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions?view=windows-11#recovery-tools-partition): 
          Select OS partition: `sel par 1` → Verify it's the OS partition: `det par`

         ```bash
         Shrink Desired=665 minimum=650
         Cre Par Pri Size=665 Id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac
         Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=WinRE
         Gpt Attributes=0x8000000000000001
         ```
      2. [EFI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions?view=windows-11#system-partition) and [MSR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions?view=windows-11#microsoft-reserved-partition-msr): 
          Select OS partition: `sel par 2` → Verify it's the OS partition: `det par`

         ```bash
         Shrink Desired=388 Minimum=388
         Cre Par EFI Size=100
         Format Quick Fs=FAT32 Label=EFI
         Assign Letter=Y
         Cre Par Msr Size=16
         ```
   5. Get OS partition drive letter: `lis vol` → `exit` 
       <sup>*(`C:` is usually not the OS drive letter in WinPE/WinRE)*</sup>
6. Configure EFI boot:

   ```bash
   ::# Create EFI directories and enter:
       MkDir "Y:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot"
       Cd /d "Y:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot"

   ::# Create EFI boot structure:
       BootRec /Fixboot

       ::# If Access Denied error occurs (C: is OS partition):
           BcdBoot C:\Windows /s C: /f UEFI

   ::# Resolve any other boot issues:
       BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD
   ```

   Remove EFI mountpoint: `DiskPart` → `Sel Vol Y` → `Remove` → `Exit`
7. Reboot via `wpeutil reboot`, then configure [WinRE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-recovery-environment--windows-re--technical-reference) once booted back to Windows:

   1. Open an *Admin* Terminal: **<kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>** → *Open*: `powershell` → **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>**+*OK*
   2. Mount WinRE partition via `DiskPart`: 
       `lis vol` → `sel vol #` → Verify: `det par` → `Assign Letter=Z` → `Exit`
   3. Extract `WinRE.wim` from the Windows install USB's `sources\install.wim`||`.esd`:

      ```bash
      # Get list of images [indexes] within the ESD/WIM:
        Dism /Get-ImageInfo /ImageFile:"E:\sources\install.wim"

      # Mount install.wim||.esd (usually index 1: Home | 6: Pro):
        MkDir "C:\Mount" ; Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:"E:\sources\install.wim" /Index:1 /MountDir:"C:\Mount" /ReadOnly

      # Copy WinRE.wim:
        Xcopy "C:\Mount\Windows\System32\Recovery\WindowsRE\WinRE.wim" "C:"
        # If hidden file: Xcopy /H

      # Unmount image, discard changes:
        Dism /Unmount-Image /MountDir:"C:\Mount" /Discard
      ```
   4. ```bash
      # Copy WinRE.wim:
        MkDir "Z:\Recovery\WindowsRE" ; Xcopy "C:\WinRE.wim" "Z:\Recovery\WindowsRE"

      # Disable WinRE:
        ReAgentC /Disable

      # Set Custom WinRE Path:
        ReAgentC /SetREimage /Path "Z:\Recovery\WindowsRE"

      # Enable WinRE and verify:
        ReAgentC /Enable ; ReAgentC /Info

      # Cleanup:
        Del "C:\WinRE.wim" ; RmDir "C:\Mount"
      ```
   5. Remove WinRE mount point: `DiskPart` → `sel vol z` → `remove` → `exit`

Comment: Will your proposed procedure, somehow, affect my disk 1 partitions or data (disk 1 is *not* my system disk)? Besides backups, should I physically remove my data disk1 before starting that mbr to gpt procedure and add it after procedure is complete? Anyway, if I remove my disk1 before starting the procedure and later connect it to a machine with a gpt boot disk 0, will I still be able to access my disk 1 partitions data E:, F: and G: data? Thx!

Comment: @caecilius These steps only affect the drive to which is being worked on, regardless of how many drives are installed. `mbr2gpt` requires specifying a disk #, which is ascertained from #4.1 - not specifying a drive will cause it to error out _(see linked to man page)_. Non-OS drives can be converted to GPT w/ no data loss, as `mbr2gpt` doesn't affect data, it's simply changing the partition table from MBR to GPT. `mbr2gpt` can also convert boot and WinRE partitions, however it overcomplicates the process, coupled w/ your boot & WinRE partitions not being the optimal size for EFI boot.

Comment: I'd recommend removing the mount drive letter for the EFI partition _before_ running the `bcdboot` command. Otherwise, it may bake the letter into the BCD database instead of `\Device\HarddiskVolume`N as the `device` entry in Windows Boot Manager.This is what I observed in Windows 11. Neither `bcdboot` nor `bootrec` needed the EFI partition mounted. At the least. confirm with `bcdedit /enum all`.

Comment: @kkm it's necessary to mount the EFI partition in order to run `BootRec /FixBoot`, as you must be within the EFI directory to not receive an access denied error; AFAIK, this didn't change in Win11. The drive letter wouldn't be registered in the BCD Store since it's the GUID of the EFI partition that tells Windows where to locate the boot files.

Comment: @JW0914, ah, thank you! If I understand you, the `bcdedit /enum` _displays_ `device` entry as a letter if the ESP partition is mounted under a letter, but _stores_ a pointer to it differently? If at all—I _vaguely_ remember a GPT disk can have only one ESP, and it has a manifest GUID assigned to it in the GPT spec, so what's the point storing it?.. _(Thinks aloud.)_ And UEFI was supposed to simplify it all… I spent a day fighting surprises after restoring to new hardware, even though my B&R software took care of system disk driver mismatch/I_B_D automagically. Your A. was crucial, thanks!

Comment: “…to run `BootRec /FixBoot` [...] you must be within the EFI directory to not receive an access denied error”—wow, I didn't know that! saw that error many times, but didn't know that the solution is so simple. If only I could upvote your answer twice! You won't mind adding this bit of knowledge into it? Better that discovering it in comments, and bootrec is barely documented.